# Replace logic from switch with generic code

Tags: go, sqlx

I have a place in code where database query is performed.
Code is not mine and I may not make decisions regarding it's architecture.
Recently, we got a task to perform couple of additional queries.
My superiors decided to put the additional queries in the same piece of database code.
Now they want me to optimize somehow that part of the code.
All those `if`s and `switch`es "pierce their eyes".

We use [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) for database queries.
I have decided to make 2 `map`s with query type as `key`, and concrete `struct`/`SQL`, as data.
This reduced visual noise significantly, but I came here to ask if there is something else I could do?
Below is example code, I believe it is self-explanatory, but do ask for clarifications if needed:

```
/*
     I will use UI windows as an example.
     The point is that all window types have some common properties,
         and some properties specific to each window type.
*/

type ProgressBar struct {

    X                   int
    Y                   int
    Width               int
    Height              int

    LowestValue         int
    Highestvalue        int
    CurrentPosition     int
}

type TextBox struct {

    X                   int
    Y                   int
    Width               int
    Height              int

    TextLength          int
    TextContent         string

}

type Calendar struct {

    X                  int
    Y                  int
    Width              int
    Height             int

    SelectedDate       time.Time
}

var (
    // holds specific SQL query for each window type
    queries             map[int] string
    // each window type has it's own function that returns struct for storing query results
    scanStructs         map[int]func() interface{}

    // since Go has no enum type, we have to simulate them like below
    progressbar     =   1
    textbox         =   2
    calendar        =   3

)

func init(){

    queries                     =   make(map[int]string)
    scanStructs                 =   make(map[int]func() interface{})

    scanStructs[progressbar]    =   func() interface{} { return ProgressBar{} }
    scanStructs[textbox]        =   func() interface{} { return TextBox{} }
    scanStructs[calendar]       =   func() interface{} { return Calendar{} }

    queries[progressbar]        =   "SELECT * FROM progress_bars"
    queries[textbox]            =   "SELECT * FROM textboxes"
    queries[calendar]           =   "SELECT * FROM calendars"

}
 
// I am providing non-refactored version for comparison
func OriginalPerformSqlQuery(type int) ([]interface{}, error) {

    query := string

    switch type {
        case progressbar:
            query =     "SELECT * FROM progress_bars"
        case textbox:
            query =     "SELECT * FROM textboxes"
        case calendar:
            query =     "SELECT * FROM calendars"
        default:  
            return interface{}, 
                   fmt.Errorf("unknown window type")
    }

    rows, err := db.Queryx(query)
    if err != nil {
        return interface{}, 
               fmt.Errorf("db.Queryx() failed: %v", err)
    }

    defer func() { _ = rows.Close() }()

    result := make([]interface{}, 0)

    for rows.Next() {

        switch type {
            case progressbar:
                r     :=     ProgressBar{}

                if err := rows.StructScan(&r); err != nil {
                      return interface{}, 
                             fmt.Errorf("rows.StructScan() failed: %v", err)
                }

                result = append(result, r)

            case textbox:
                r     :=     TextBox{}

                if err := rows.StructScan(&r); err != nil {
                      return interface{}, 
                             fmt.Errorf("rows.StructScan() failed: %v", err)
                }

                result = append(result, r)

            case calendar:
                r     :=     Calendar{}

                if err := rows.StructScan(&r); err != nil {
                      return interface{}, 
                             fmt.Errorf("rows.StructScan() failed: %v", err)
                }

                result = append(result, r)
        }
    }

    return result, nil

}

func PerformSqlQuery(type int) ([]interface{}, error) {

    query, exists = queries[type]
    if !exists {
        return interface{}, 
               fmt.Errorf("unknown window type")
    }

    rows, err := db.Queryx(query)
    if err != nil {
        return interface{}, 
               fmt.Errorf("db.Queryx() failed: %v", err)
    }

    defer func() { _ = rows.Close() }()

    result := make([]interface{}, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        // get required destination struct
        r := scanStructs[type]()

        if err := rows.StructScan(&r); err != nil {
            return interface{}, 
                   fmt.Errorf("rows.StructScan() failed: %v", err)
        }

        result = append(result, r)
    }

    return result, nil

}
```

Answer (score 4):

- You can change the window types to `const` and type it:

```
type windowType int

const (
    progressbar windowType = iota + 1
    textbox
    calendar
)
```

- You can change the map init to composite literal

```
type helperData struct {
    query       string
    scanStruct  func() interface{}
}

var helperMap = map[windowType]helperData{
    progressbar: {
        query:       "SELECT * FROM progress_bars",
        scanStruct:  func() interface{} { return ProgressBar{} },
    },
    textbox: {
        query:       "SELECT * FROM textboxes",
        scanStruct:  func() interface{} { return TextBox{} },
    },
    calendar: {
        query:       "SELECT * FROM calendars",
        scanStruct:  func() interface{} { return Calendars{} },
    }
}
```